# What is the remote node when running ignite?

Tags: version, ignite

I get this error when I run some unit tests.

Caused by: org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Local node and remote node have different version numbers (node will not join, Ignite does not support rolling updates, so versions must be exactly the same) [locBuildVer=2.7.0, rmtBuildVer=2.7.5, locNodeAddrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo0, 127.0.0.1], rmtNodeAddrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo0, 127.0.0.1], locNodeId=4e06aca7-989b-4f0d-af9f-b6cd076fe0a0, rmtNodeId=52cab0e0-6527-4a83-aa13-ae192f6e4068].

I would like to know what is the remote node. I'm running the unit tests locally and the unit tests are starting and stoping a local ignite server. And how to get them matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

locBuildVer=2.7.0, rmtBuildVer=2.7.5

All nodes in your cluster need to be exactly the same version. Here one node is at version 2.7.0 and another version is at 2.7.5

locNodeAddrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo0, 127.0.0.1], rmtNodeAddrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo0, 127.0.0.1]

This means that both servers are on your local machine. Use VisualVM, or the included JPS tool (comes with the jdk) to see the running java processes.

Stop the relevant java processes, and restart, making sure all your Node(s) are on the same version.

When you start Ignite, it has a message specifying the version.

For example:
 **ver. 2.7.6#20190911-sha1:21f7ca41**

Also check out GridGain, built on top of Ignite, allowing rolling updates, a feature that permits nodes with different versions of GridGain to co-exist in one cluster while you roll out new versions.
https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/rolling-upgrades